# Tablas para relacion uno a muchos o muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, relaciones

Sin querer extender mucho, quiero saber si me pueden ayudar con esto:

Tengo una tabla con datos del empleado y otra tabla con las asignaciones que percibe los distintos empleados, como bono vacacional, bono nocturno etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, la relación entre estas 2 tablas es que, un empleado puede tener muchas asignaciones, y una asignación la puede tener muchos empleados.

Tendría que tener, según creo yo, una tercera tabla que relacione cada empleado con cada asignación. En un principio la hice así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo tener en cuenta, por ejemplo, que un empleado puede tener la asignación de bono nocturno en el mes de junio, pero también tendría esa misma asignación para el mes de julio con un monto distinto.

Ya probé con esta estructura, hice cada llave primaria (id_empleado, id_asignación) y en la tercera tabla hice las llaves foráneas de las otras dos tablas.

El error surge en la tercera tabla cuando trato de hacer varios registros con el mismo id_empleado, o con un mismo id_asignación, en los casos cuando el valor en la columna "monto" y "fecha" cambian.

Por favor no se si estoy planteando la tablas mal, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si `asigna_empleado` determina la asignación por empleado y fecha, el problema que tienes, es que has definido mal la `PK` de esta tabla, debería ser en todo caso `id_empleado + id_asignacion + fecha`. O en su defecto, habría que generar un autonumérico para esta tabla y que el mismo sea PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está bien que crees una relación (tabla) intermedia, me surge la siguiente pregunta:

**¿La asignación puede relacionarse con el empleado más de una vez en el mes o es única en el mes para ese empleado?**.

**1) Supongamos que le respuesta es:** la asignación se puede relacionar con el empleado una sola vez en el mes.

```
asigna_empleado:
  id_empleado: PK, FK
  id_asignacion: PK, FK
  mes: entero, PK
  anio: entero, PK
  monto
```

Esto evita que se registro la misma relación entre empleado y asignación en un mes y año dado. También permite que se cambie el monto dependiendo el mes en cuestión.

El problema es que se debe actualizar todos los meses las asignaciones de empleados provocando que se generan muchos registros.

**2) Supongamos que la respuesta es:** La asignación puede cambiar en cualquier día del mes.

Con esto se debería definir una relación (tabla) temporal:

```
asigna_empleado:
  id_empleado: PK, FK
  id_asignacion: PK, FK
  desde: fecha, PK
  hasta: fecha, por defecto en NULL
  monto
```

El atributo **hasta** con valor NULL indica que esa tupla no tiene fecha de finalización definida. Ejemplo: un registro con atributo **desde** con valor '2019-04-01' y **hasta** en NULL, indica el monto desde el **01/04/2019** a la fecha.

la relación debe cumplir algunas reglas:

- No deben existir dos tuplas con el mismo **id_empleado** y **id_relacion** con el atributo **hasta** en NULL.
- Para las tuplas con el mismo **id_empleado** y **id_relacion** no debe haber superposición de los atributos **desde** y **hasta** con otra tupla.
- No se permiten eliminaciones o modificaciones de otro atributo que no sea **hasta**

El problema de esta definición es que se olviden de actualizar el atributo **hasta** cuando le deban quitar la asignación a un empleado.

Las consultas se vuelven más complejas para obtener los datos.

La ventaja es que se tienen pocos registros, solamente se actualizan las fechas e insertan nuevos registros cuando cambia el monto o se le quita la asignación al empleado.

Otra ventaje es que se permite más de un monto en el mismo mes.

Son las dos apróximaciones que se me ocurren por el momento. Cada una tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, seguramente me he olvidado de nombrar algunas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, con respecto a lo que propones, efectivamente, la asignación se relaciona con el empleado una sola vez en el mes, por supuesto, al siguiente mes cambia el monto y se me generan muchos registros, pero mi sistema debe conservar el valor de cada asignación por mes para futuros reportes